# Adding Cookie to SOAPpy Request

Tags: python, web-services, soap, soappy

I'm trying to send a SOAP request using SOAPpy as the client. I've found some documentation stating how to add a cookie by extending SOAPpy.HTTPTransport, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried to use the example [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/444758/),
but the server I'm trying to send the request to started throwing 415 errors, so I'm trying to accomplish this without using ClientCookie, or by figuring out why the server is throwing 415's when I do use it. I suspect it might be because ClientCookie uses urllib2 & http/1.1, whereas SOAPpy uses urllib & http/1.0

Does someone know how to make ClientCookie use http/1.0, if that is even the problem, or a way to add a cookie to the SOAPpy headers without using ClientCookie? If tried this code using other services, it only seems to throw errors when sending requests to Microsoft servers.

I'm still finding my footing with python, so it could just be me doing something dumb.

```
import sys, os, string
from SOAPpy import WSDL,HTTPTransport,Config,SOAPAddress,Types
import ClientCookie

Config.cookieJar = ClientCookie.MozillaCookieJar()

class CookieTransport(HTTPTransport):
  def call(self, addr, data, namespace, soapaction = None, encoding = None,
    http_proxy = None, config = Config):

    if not isinstance(addr, SOAPAddress):
      addr = SOAPAddress(addr, config)

    cookie_cutter = ClientCookie.HTTPCookieProcessor(config.cookieJar)
    hh = ClientCookie.HTTPHandler()
    hh.set_http_debuglevel(1)

    # TODO proxy support
    opener = ClientCookie.build_opener(cookie_cutter, hh)

    t = 'text/xml';
    if encoding != None:
      t += '; charset="%s"' % encoding
    opener.addheaders = [("Content-Type", t),
          ("Cookie", "Username=foobar"), # ClientCookie should handle
          ("SOAPAction" , "%s" % (soapaction))]

    response = opener.open(addr.proto + "://" + addr.host + addr.path, data)
    data = response.read()

    # get the new namespace
    if namespace is None:
      new_ns = None
    else:
      new_ns = self.getNS(namespace, data)

    print '\n' * 4 , '-'*50
    # return response payload
    return data, new_ns


url = 'http://www.authorstream.com/Services/Test.asmx?WSDL'
proxy = WSDL.Proxy(url, transport=CookieTransport)
print proxy.GetList()
```

Comment: I might have figured this out, trying something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 415 is because of incorrect content-type header.

Install httpfox for firefox or whatever tool (wireshark, Charles or Fiddler) to track what headers are you sending. Try Content-Type: application/xml.

```
...
t = 'application/xml';
if encoding != None:
  t += '; charset="%s"' % encoding
...
```

If you trying to send file to the web server use Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: i've since discovered that thats exactly the problem, im having trouble overriding it though. I'm trying to set it in the code above, but it's not taking.

Answer (score 0):

A nice  hack to use cookies with SOAPpy calls
[Using Cookies with SOAPpy calls](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/444758-how-to-add-cookiesheaders-to-soappy-calls/)